# The use of tags outside the Q&A sites

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, jobs, tag-wiki

Tags are used to categorize posts on SE sites, but what I only realized recently is that they're getting used in other parts of the SE network as well, in particular on Careers/SO Jobs.

If you click on the shiny new Jobs tab on SO and then look for postgresql jobs, hovering over the postgresql tag will show you the following text:

> [...]  Please mention your exact PostgreSQL version when asking
>   questions. Questions concerning administration or advanced features
>   are best directed to dba.stackexchange.com.

Doing the same for ember.js shows the following:

> Ember.js is an MVC application framework written in JavaScript.
>   Consider making your question easier to answer by using the
>   pre-configured templates from this tag's wiki (click learn more).

Those tag wikis make sense on SO, they're pretty non-sensical on job postings. Tags and tag wikis were designed only with Q&A in mind, but now they're used in other places with noticeable rough edges like these. Being able to subscribe to tags or view the frequently asked questions in that tag also doesn't seem to make much sense on Careers.

The absence of capitalization and the use of dashes instead of spaces in some tags is a minor issue on the Q&A sites in general, but it gets much more of an eyesore on your CV on Careers.

Should the tag system be changed in any way to adapt to the new ways it is used now? Tag wikis have plenty of problems anyway, but maybe they should be split in some consistent way into describing the topic and then separately on instructions on how to use the tag. Is it time to properly capitalize tags?

These issues are not particularly major, but they do make tags look rather unpolished the moment they're used outside their original purpose. And this is probably not getting better as more SE projects might use tags for their own purposes.

Answer (score 5):

As of the latest build we have removed the tag hovers from most of the /jobs tabs.  We will get the rest in the next build of Careers.  We tend to agree that we might need a new hover menu for /jobs but that hasn't been designed yet.  We have also added a link to jobs by tag in the other hover menu if the tag has enough jobs on Careers.

Comment: I didn't expect this to be a bug, I thought the hoves were intentional. Any thoughts on how hard/impossible it would be to add proper capitalization to tags?

Comment: Remaining parts of Careers have now been fixed too.